# Login is not picking up user_id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication

I have two PHP pages:

1. A login page for email/password.
2. An index page for viewing data. This data view differs depending on if a user is logged in or not.

My login page passes the "submit" button and redirects to the index.php when I enter the login correctly. The validation works correctly if I type a wrong login.

However, the user_id doesn't seem to be carrying over into the index.php. I cannot print it out in debug as it says user_id is invalid.

I know the database is being read because it is displaying data on the page.

Both pages have a session_start(); at the top.

Any thoughts about how to get the user_id to carry over from login to index?

Below is my login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";

// Redirect to index.php if use clicks cancel button
if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}

$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';


// If we have POST data, process it
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {

    // Check for email and password
    if ( strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email and password are required";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;

    // Check for at-sign in email
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;

    } else {

        $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :em AND password = :pw');
        $stmt->execute(array( ':em' => $_POST['email'], ':pw' => $check));
        $check = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($check === false) {
            // Else redirect to the login page
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Incorrect Password";
            error_log("Login fail ".$_POST['email']." $check");
            header("Location: login.php");
            return;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
            error_log("Login success ".$_POST['email']);
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;

        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <?php

        // Message View of Errors
        if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }

        ?>

        <h1>Please Log In</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="name"><br/>
            <label for="id_1723">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="return doValidate();">
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
function doValidate() {
    console.log('Validating...');
    try {
        pw = document.getElementById('id_1723').value;
        console.log("Validating pw="+pw);
        if (pw == null || pw == "") {
            alert("Both fields must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";
require_once "util.php";

// Fetch Profiles
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM profile");
$profiles = array();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    $profiles[] = $row;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <br /><br />

    <h1>Resume Entry</h1>

    <?php

        flashMessages();

        // Login our Logout
        if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
            echo('<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>'."\n");
        } else {
            echo('<p><a href="login.php">Please log in</a></p>'."\n");
        }

        // Show the table
        if ( count($profiles) > 0 ) {
            echo ( '<table border="1">'."\n");
            echo ( '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Headline</th>');
            if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) { 
                echo ( '<th>Action</th>' );
            }

            echo ("<tr>\n");

            foreach ( $profiles as $profile ) {
                echo ( "<tr><td>\n" );
                echo ( '<a href="view.php?profile_id='.$profile['profile_id'].'">' );
                echo ( htmlentities($profile['first_name']) );
                echo ( ' ' );
                echo ( htmlentities($profile['last_name']) );
                echo ( '</a>' );
                echo ( "</td><td>\n" );
                echo ( htmlentities($profile['headline']) );
                echo ( "</td>" );
                if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) { 
                    echo ( "<td>\n" );
                    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] == $profile['user_id'] ) {
                        echo ( '<a href="edit.php?profile_id='.$profile['profile_id'].'">Edit</a>' );
                        echo ( ' ' );
                        echo ( '<a href="delete.php?profile_id='.$profile['profile_id'].'">Delete</a>' );
                    }
                    echo ( "</td>" );
                }
                echo ( "</tr>\n" );
            }
            echo ( "</table>\n" );
        }

        if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
            echo ( '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p>'."\n" );
        }

    ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looking at the code above (login), it seems you have not set session value `user_id` at all, only `name`

Comment: as an aside, do you really intend to fetch all the users? why not just use a `WHERE` clause in `index` using said `user_id`

Comment: @Ghost Where and how do I set user_id? Can you please offer guidance here?

Comment: I don't know if I need to fetch all users. This was sample code provided to us for assignment. I can't speak for the reasoning behind it. :/

Comment: if thats the case, since your intent if just to fetch that particular row. use a `WHERE` clause in your query, and bind that user id. on that success block inside login, you'll need to set user id too, just like the answer (comment) below

Answer (score 1):

In the success block of your login.php, you're not setting `$_SESSION['user_id']` anywhere.

Comment: Can you please explain how to set this? Sorry, I'm totally new here to PHP, just trying to get through a class.

Comment: Please note the changes to the code where you log a successful login.
} else {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
            error_log("Login success ".$_POST['email']);
            //query for the login in then set the session variable from that.
           $_SESSION['login_id'] = $qry_result['id']; //or something similar. Y
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This did exactly the trick. To be sure I understand some concepts here: So just because a query is called, the user_id still needs to be set in a session. Likewise, the reason the session is set in the "success" message is because this message carries over to the next page. Am I understanding this correctly? I greatly appreciate your time and help in guiding a new PHP programmer here.